# React-Router v6 : Lazy Loaded other library routes and components are not loading

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am new to **React & React-Router@v6**.

I was upgrading to **react-router v6** from **v5.3**, and updated my local routes to v6 architecture.

**v5 route file**

```
import { lazy } from 'react';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

const SchoolRoutes = () => {
    const login = lazy(() => import('./login/login'));

    // Component from Other Library as home page and acts as initial route
    const home = lazy(() => import('@portal-school/home').then(({ Home }) => ({ default: Home })));

    // Routes from Other libs
    const studentRoutes = lazy(() => import('@portal-school/school').then(({ Students }) => ({ default: Students, })));
    const activitiesRoutes = lazy(() => import('@portal-school/school').then(({ Activities }) => ({ default: Activities, })));
    const reportRoutes = lazy(() => import('@portal-school/reports').then(({ ReportRoutes }) => ({ default: ReportRoutes, })));

  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={home} />
      <Route exact path="/login" component={login} />
      <Route path="/students" component={studentRoutes} />
      <Route path="/activities" component={activitiesRoutes} />
      <Route path="/school-reports" component={reportRoutes} />
    </Switch>
  );
};
export default SchoolRoutes;
```

**v6 route file**

```
import React,{ lazy } from 'react';
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';

const SchoolRoutes = () => {
  const Login = lazy(() => import('./login/login'));

//   Below is the home component that to be loaded.
  const Home = lazy(() => import('@portal-school/home').then(({ UserLogs }) => ({ default: UserLogs })));

//   Below are the routes from other libs to be loaded.
  const StudentRoutes = lazy(() => import('@portal-school/school').then(({ Students }) => ({ default: Students, })));
  const ActivitiesRoutes = lazy(() => import('@portal-school/school').then(({ Activities }) => ({ default: Activities, })));
  const ReportRoutes = lazy(() => import('@portal-school/reports').then(({ ReportRoutes }) => ({ default: ReportRoutes, })));

  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
      <Route path="/students/*" element={<StudentRoutes />} />
      <Route path="/activities/*" element={<ActivitiesRoutes />} />
      <Route path="/school-reports/*" element={<ReportRoutes />} />
    </Routes>
  );
};
export default SchoolRoutes;
```

**Main App component**

```
function App(){
return (
  <BrowserRouter>
     <AppBar className="app-header">
         <div className="school-logo"></div>
     </AppBar>
     <SideMenu/>
     //Injecting Routes Below
     <main className="main-blk">
        <Suspense fallback={<CircularProgress />}> // Circular Progress is loading

          // School Routes file injected below.
          <SchoolRoutes/>

        </Suspense>
     </main>
  </BrowserRouter>
)
}
```

So While trying to access the routes, the home screen is not loading, only **Suspense fallback Message Renders**, and when I try to access other Route Links, there is the same issue.

Components are not loading through the routes. Can anyone share a solution ?.

**Update:** I solved by moving the Suspense from App to SchoolRoutes.

**Old SchoolRoutes File**

```
<Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
      <Route path="/students/*" element={<StudentRoutes />} />
      <Route path="/activities/*" element={<ActivitiesRoutes />} />
      <Route path="/school-reports/*" element={<ReportRoutes />} />
</Routes>
```

**Updated SchoolRoutes File**

```
<Suspense fallback={<CircularProgress />}>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
      <Route path="/students/*" element={<StudentRoutes />} />
      <Route path="/activities/*" element={<ActivitiesRoutes />} />
      <Route path="/school-reports/*" element={<ReportRoutes />} />
    </Routes>
<Suspense/>
```

Comment: I think you might want to move all the dynamic component imports ***out*** of `SchoolRoutes` so they aren't being redeclared each render cycle. Where is `React.Suspense` being rendered? Can you include all relevant code you are working with? See [mcve].

Comment: Hi @DrewReese, I updated the samples, I want to let you know that the issue was resolved by moving the Suspense from App to Routes, could you clarify to me what happened?

Comment: Dunno, I would expect the `Suspense` component to function the same regardless where it's rendered in the ReactTree so long as it's higher in the ReactTree than the dynamically/lazily imported components.